Reasons for the lack of contract extensions to a senior researcher who is doing his/her duty
Let's consider that you are a "Senior Researcher and Lecturer" in a University that is ranked in the 100-150th position range, and you have a fix-term contract (around 2 years). You are doing your duty and it looks like that everyone is happy about you and your research.
Also, during your employment your line manager (professor who is co-head of the Lab together with other 2-3 other professors) proposes you to apply for an "Assistant Professor" position in a higher ranked University, writing you a very nice reference letter, strongly recommending you for that position.
Then, unfortunately you do not get the position, and towards the end of your contract your line manager tells you that there is not funding anymore to support you.
However, you learn that another supply of funding is coming to the whole Lab to eventually "feed" the entire Lab for 4-5 other years. However, they tell you that the money is destined to other people, as new PhD students, and nothing is there for you.
Reading between the lines, is the funding really allocated for other projects or new students, or it is a "nice" way to tell you that "you are not good enough to stay in this University"?
In other words, is this a common practice in the Universities not to fund you anymore (even though your are doing your duty/what they expect from you) as an unpleasant way to say "you did not pass our evaluation", or, for real, there is not funding anymore for an expensive Senior researcher as you (in comparison to PhD students)?

Limited term positions come to an end. Not all grants fund all types of positions. Don’t read too much into things, particularly the supposed motivations of others.

Sounds like a false dichotomy.  There's a large area in between where they could use the funding to continue your contract, and your performance is satisfactory, but there are other people or projects which they simply think are a higher priority.

Funding to support research staff is less common. Funding to support PhD students is the most common, and makes the most sense because the role of the university is to educate students and confer degrees.
Congratulations on doing a good job and earning the respect of your supervisor, and their support in growing your independent career. However, you are in a temporary contract position and your support has run out. Such positions are by nature temporary and you should have been using this time to secure your next, permanent position. Growing comfortable in a soft-money temporary position is not a good career move. Time to move on.

Indeed. Finding a new position takes time. At the very least, a solid multi-prong job search should have started by the end of the first year. That may have included trying to extend the temporary position, find some other temporary position, as well as applying for multiple permanent positions at multiple institutions.

If OP wants to be upset about something, they might be upset if the people in a position to mentor them did not ever point out the importance of looking for a next job while holding a temporary position. However, it's unclear whether that's actually the case or whether OP simply didn't hear them; it does seem that they encouraged them to apply for at least one job. Maybe that was the only thing they ever said, maybe they had been nudging it for months and finally gave a specific suggestion after no movement.

The first discussion I have with a new post-doc in my group covers (1) the job of a post-doc is to find a job, and (2) here is how we will set you up to start looking for that job within 12 months.

@JonCuster Part of the problem may also be that from OP's description it sounds like they have/had a post-doc job, but the institution decided to name it differently than is typical at least to me, so perhaps they did not realize their job was a post-doc (though, looking through their post history, if the job they were asking about is the job they took, it does appear that other users on this site, at least, told them it was a post doc).

@DanielHatton Shocked and upset that their fixed-term job is fixed-term and ends at the end of the contract?

@DanielHatton Where is here? Everywhere I have worked it was understood that the nature of the contract is temporary, as is the funding that supports it. What job should they be given? Who is going to pay for it? If the outcome is that postdocs must be supported indefinitely or be offered severance, then the only logical outcome I see is PhD programs become extremely restricted with limited graduates, and postdoctoral positions all but disappear.

@DanielHatton - a perusal of questions over on Workplace SE will yield many about contracts coming to an end. It is far from unique to academia.
